# How to get <span> element when all spanned text selected?

Tags: html, contenteditable

In a content-editable div, I want to surround selected text with a `<span>`, or modify an existing `<span>` when I select all the text within it. I can do the first, but not the second.

In the second case, if I have `A<span>B</span>C` and I select B, the selection shows the `anchorNode` as `A`, the `focusNode` as `C`, and `toString()` returns `B`. The parent node is the enclosing paragraph, not the `<span>`. I cannot find any way to distinguish between selecting `B` in `A<span>B</span>C` and in `ABC`, since I can't find any way to discover the existence of the `<span>` element that surrounds `B` in the first case. There must be a way to do this, surely? Can someone tell me how to do this?

Here is the code:

```
var sel = window.getSelection();
var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
var selected = range.compareBoundaryPoints(range.START_TO_END, range);
if (selected > 0) {    // some text is selected
  var el = range.commonAncestorContainer;
  //
  // would expect to find el == <span> if selection is B
  // in <p>A<span>B</span>C<p>, but find <p> instead!
  //
  //... code to surround selection with new span or to process
  //    existing span... but there is never an existing span!
}
```

Comment: What environment are you trying to do this in? Do you have more code?

Comment: Added some code above. What I'm doing: Using Firefox, double-clicking on a word in a paragraph inside a content-editable div, adding a span (which works), then double clicking on same word, trying to modify the span I just inserted, and putting a breakpoint in the browser's debugger just after the assignment to "el". The value of "el" is the span ONLY if I click the button to modify the span immediately after inserting it -- if I click somewhere else, then come back and double-click the word again, it fails to find the span, even though the text selected is entirely inside it.

Comment: Because it doesn't find the span, I end up with <p>A<span><span>B</span></span>C</p>.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come up with a rather horrible workaround for the above problem. To test if the selection is the whole of a `<span>` element, I clone the range, which, when it is the whole span, contains the span preceded and followed by empty strings. So what I do is to remove any of these, and check if what I'm left with is a single span element. If that's the case, I take the next element after the start of the original range, which will be the `<span>`:

```
var el = range.commonAncestorContainer;
var copy = range.cloneContents();
while (copy.childNodes.length > 1 && copy.firstChild.nodeValue === "") {
  copy.removeChild(copy.firstChild);
}
while (copy.childNodes.length > 1 && copy.lastChild.nodeValue === "") {
  copy.removeChild(copy.lastChild);
}
if (copy.childNodes.length == 1 && copy.childNodes[0] instanceof HTMLSpanElement) {
  el = range.startContainer.nextSibling;
}
```

This works, but it's not very appealing. I'd be happy if anyone has a neater solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Range.commonAncestorContainer** has a property called **parentElement**. It is the parent of the selected text.

---

In the code snippet, both London and Paris are wrapped with an **span** element.

```js
const text = "<p>Hello from <span>London</span> and <span>Paris</span></p>"
const parser = new DOMParser();
const html = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html").body.innerHTML
const editor = document.querySelector('div[contenteditable]')
editor.innerHTML = html


function getParent() {
  var selection = window.getSelection();
  if (selection.rangeCount) {
    const range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
    const parent = range.commonAncestorContainer.parentElement;

    document.querySelector("#result").innerText = parent instanceof HTMLSpanElement
    if (parent instanceof HTMLSpanElement) {
      console.log(parent)
    }
  }
}


document.querySelector("button").onclick = getParent;
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="w-100 p-5 border" contenteditable>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <button class="btn btn-primary">Get Text</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row align-items-center">
    <div class="col">
      <p>Is Is parent instanceof HTMLSpanElement?  <span id="result"></span> </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This only works as long as you select text within the span, not the entire span contents. E.g. if you select the whole of the word "London", the common ancestor is the <p> which encloses the <span>, and the parentElement is then the enclosing <div> of the <p>. I'm trying to deal with the case where the selection is the entire span content. It seems that when you select "London"in the above, you're actually selecting "<span>London</span>", and there doesn't seem to be any easy way to distinguish "London" from "<span>London</span>"

Comment: Consider changing the font color by wrapping text in <span style="color:red">. If the text is not the whole span content (e.g. "ondo" inside "London"), then I wrap it, to give e.g. <span style="color:blue">L<span style="color:red">ondo</span>n</span>. If I select the whole span, I end up with <span style="color:red"><span style="color:blue">London</span></span>, which is still blue, because I'm wrapping outside the existing span rather than inside. In this case I want to just change the enclosing span from blue to red.

Comment: @user1636349 London is  instanceof Text while <span>London</span> is instanceof HTMLSpanElement. If you add all the scenarios with examples [action, expected-result], I will help you. If you do so, include it in your question.

Comment: Well, in your example, if you select the word "London" and click "Get text", nothing happens (because the whole span is selected, and its parent is <p>), but if you select "ondo" from the middle of the word, it says "<span>London</span>". I'd like it so that if you select "ondo" from the middle of the word, it says "ondo", and if you select "London", it displays "<span>London</span>".

Comment: As I said below, I have a workaround, but it's a total kludge. So a neater solution would be much appreciated!